# Превратить строчку "100, 100" в перечисление целых чисел 100, 100

Tags: python, combobox, tuple

Tkinter, Pysimplegui имеют combobox, который хранит значения int или str через запятую. Я так понимаю, проще будет как-то поделить str на int и чтобы это всё стало tuple.
Короче, combobox имеет значение `"100,100"`, на выходе должен получиться кортеж `(100, 100)`.

Надеюсь, Вы меня поняли.

**UPD:** Короче, мне нужно сделать комбо с числами разных или одинаковых значений по 2. Типа `['100, 100', '12, 34', '24327, 241627']` Если это можно сделать без string, а, например, через скобки (я пытался), то спасибо.

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем.

Не стоит разводить воду, абстрагируйтесь, приведите минимальный пример

Comment: Обязательно `Tuple` или `List` тоже подойдет? Приведите примеры вида `значение => результат`

Comment: примите текущее решение и составьте новый вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не понятно, что вы хотите. Да, значения, из которых юзер выбирает, нужны выть в форме списка или кортежи, например

```
sg.Combo(("красный", "синий", "зеленый"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
или

```
sg.Combo([100, 200, 300])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ваше

```
sg.Combo((100, 100))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не имеет смысла — *вы хотите, чтобы юзер выбирал между двумя **одинаковыми** возможностями?*

---

Всё равно, я отвечу на ваш вопрос. И так, у вас строка чисел с запятой и пробелом (`", "`) между ними, например

```
str_of_nums = "100, 200, 300"
```

и вы хотите получить как результат список `[100, 200, 300]`.

Примените метод [.split()](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.split/) для получения списка `["100", "200", 300"]`

```
list_of_numstr = str_of_nums.split(", ")
```

и затем *[генератор списка](https://all-python.ru/osnovy/generator-spiska.html)*, для применения функции `int()` к всякому элементу этого списка:

```
list_of_nums = [int(element) for element in list_of_numstr]
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо, помогло... Последнее.

Answer (score 4):

```py
string = '100,100'
result = tuple(map(int, string.split(',')))
print(result)
```

Делаем из `string` список, разделитель - запятая, map переводит строки из списка в числа, из результата создаём кортеж.

Comment: я советую вам прочесть и следовать [pep8 на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальной документации pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (слёзно вас прошу)

Comment: @Александр, следуя pep8, Вы тоже, не называйте переменные их типом.) string - плохое название переменной

Comment: @eri, чем вам не нравится `string`? я не называю переменную `str`, что является встроенным классом. Для примера это нагляднее всего

Comment: string название базового модуля. поэтому я проявил лень и назвал s.

Comment: @Александр не понятно что внутри этой строки.

Comment: @eri так под кодом расписано что происходит. если можите перефразировать более понятно, то будет великолепно. #с телефона не очень удобно писать большие ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Логика как и в предыдущем ответе (разделение строки методом `split()`, после чего изменение типа), но синтаксис более читаемый:

```
data = "100, 100" 
converted_data = tuple(int(value) for value in data.split(','))
```

Comment: сейчас это не является ответом, отредактируйте так, чтобы был цельный код, а не несколько вставок с кодом